# likely / probable

Tags: word-usage

> 1. Seeing that you study hard, it's likely that you will get a high score.
> 2. Seeing that you study hard, it's probable that you will get a high score.

here, ***likely*** and ***probable*** are the same meaning and interchangeable, right?

Comment: We usually use future simple along with probably, and present simple with likely.

Answer (score 1):

First, the phrase, "given that" seems more appropriate here: "Given that you study hard, it's likely that you will get a high score." **Likely** and **probable** are generally interchangeable, as they are here.